# Look up dictionary value from a generic type

Tags: c#, templates, generics

Is it possible to get a value from a dictionary using a generic type as a key?

This is the behavior I want to achieve:

```cs
Manager.ForEach<T>((key, value) => {
        //Do something
});

class Manager 
{
    private Dictionary<MyEnum, T> Map = new Dictionary<MyEnum, T>();

    public void ForEach<T> (Action<MyEnum, T> callback)
    {
          // This is where I want to look up from the map using T
          // Is that even possible?
          foreach (var item in Map[T]) 
          {
              callback(item.Key, item.Value);
          }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `T` supposed to be? If you want to iterate `Map`, just use `foreach (var item in Map)`; no `T` needed. If you want to access a specific element, `T` is `T1` and no loop needed.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while typing my sample code, basically the key in my map is an Enum lets say, and T is the value, however I also want to lookup based on T without having to add the key as a parameter like here ForEach<T>(MyEnum key)

Comment: "T is the value" - if you write `<T>`, T is a type, not a value.

Comment: Go up a level, tell us what problem you're trying to solve with this code here

Comment: I might be falling into the XY problem here. What I want to do is somehow look up all the available components in my manager without having to add an extra key argument in my ForEach function and only using my type `T`. Let's say my manager has a composition of `Position[]`, `Speed[]`, `Rotation[]` instances, they can be contained in any structure (HashMap, Array, etc). I want to call `ForEach<Position>()`, `ForEach<Rotation>()` and `ForEach<Speed>()` and get all elements for each type.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeah, I was hoping there was a way to lookup using a type as a key, but I guess this is inherently wrong.

Comment: From your last comment, maybe you want [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype)?